# Pgsql how to return a value from script

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need to return a value named `tsmax` from the execution of a pgsql script.

The script is executed by and ETL datasource (Pentaho). All I can do is execute a script. I can't create functions on source database.

Below is my script. I need something like `select tsmax;` at the end, but the script block cannot do select nor return values. (I've just replaced all calculations with a label "*do some process to calculate tsmax*" to simplify the example).

```
do $$
declare tsmax timestamp;
begin
    -- do some process to calculate tsmax
    -- do some process to calculate tsmax
    tsmax = now();

    -- i want to return value tsmax
    select tsmax; -- this is an ERROR!
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use `select now()` outside of the script - that value does not change inside of a single transaction

Comment: "tsmax = now()"  is an example! The real code to calculate tsmax is longer, with cursor and executing scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You should to store value to session variable, and after execution of anonymous block, you can read this value:

```
[pavel@nemesis ~]$ echo "do \$\$ begin perform set_config('myvars.myvar', current_date::text, false); end \$\$; select current_setting('myvars.myvar'); " | psql -At postgres
DO
2018-11-13
```

`DO` command doesn't support any form of return value.

Comment: I can set config var even if I have only select grants on a database?

Comment: @Radioleao yes, but you have to use some prefix like 'myvars.'

Comment: It is  good solution. Unfortunatly, it doesn't work with ETL Pentaho (table input task): it returns the error message "No result returned by the query". I don't know why, but I guess it's because the first statement (do block) doesn't return data.